# Aligning text position and size in a button kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm struggling to get the text in a button to align in the centre of the button, it's just sitting at the bottom of the button.

I've tried changing text_size and font_size to the RoundedButton but nothing has worked so far.

```
FloatLayout:
    RoundedButton:
        size_hint: 0.417, 0.15625
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.0556, "y": 0.15}
        text: "Holding text that isn't aligning in the centre of the button'"
        color: 0,0,0,1
        text_size: self.width , self.height
        halign: "center"
        font_size: self.height - 75

<RoundedButton@Button>:
    background_normal: ""
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
    back_color: 0.2,0.6,1,1
    border_radius: 10
    font_size: '25'
    color: self.back_color
    bold: True
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.back_color
        Line:
            rounded_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, self.border_radius
            width: 1
```

and a trimmed version of the python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("mykivy.kv")
sm = WindowManager()

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm



if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Please post a minimal runnable example, your code isn't enough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Apologies, I've added some code to create a minimum runnable example

Comment: @Callum only remove `font_size: self.height - 75`: https://imgur.com/a/Dr6eAXM

Comment: If I do that it does align properly in the default window size but the font size doesn't adjust when I make the window smaller, the words just fall out of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just figured it out, if anyone wants to know the answer in future I had to set valign to "center" (as well as having halign: "center")